# Cascading kendoDropDownList, get selected text in first dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown

I'm fairly new to Kendo UI and got the basics for my code here : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

I got 2 api calls, where the first take no parameters and return a list if items (Id, Name)
The second api call take in an Id, and return a seconds list of items (also just an object with Id and Name)
From this I want to have 2 cascading kendo dropdowns. 
However my problem is the second one's url always have the id being null or empty, and I cannot figure out what is the right syntax:

```
            // First dropdown, all good
            var controllers = $("#Controller").kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Select controller...",
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: "/SharedData/GetControllers/"
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");

            // second dropdown, always hit the api method with the id being null or empty  (depending on syntax for url)
            var actions = $("#Action").kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: true,
                cascadeFrom: "controllers",
                cascadeFromField: "Id",
                optionLabel: "Select Action...",
                dataTextField: "Id",
                dataValueField: "Name",
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        // HELP:  need pass id to this route (which is id of selected controller)
                        read: "/SharedData/GetControllerActions/id=" + $("#Controller").data("kendoDropDownList").text()
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Comment: If I look at the source rendered, I see that the currently selected value is there in a span ("AdvancedSearchController" in this case).

Comment: '<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="Controller_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="Controller_option_selected">
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">AdvancedSearchController</span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
</span>
<input id="Controller" type="text" value="" name="Controller" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
</span>'

Comment: you can try initializing your second dropdown with no datasource, then add a "change" event on your first dropdown which initializes a datasource and sets the second dropdown's datasource to the newly initialized one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your datasource only gets set one time - at the time of initialization - and at this time the value of the dropdown is null. What i would do is add a change event on the first dropdown like this:

```
        var controllers = $("#Controller").kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select controller...",
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: "/SharedData/GetControllers/"
                }
            },
            change: function(e) {
               setSecondDS();
            }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");

       var setSecondDS = function() {
           //initialize your new kendo datasource here
           var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               //your stuff here
               transport:
               serverFiltering:
           });

          $("#Action").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(dataSource); 
       }
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH!  Struggled with this for hours yesterday (yep, what you posted does the job)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help @Nico